# Java: I'm not able to use the crud Repository deleteByID() to remove instance from my entity

Tags: java, spring, repository

As a beginner in OOP, I'm facing a lot of problems in my exercise.
I would like to know, how can I remove `employe` from `myrunner.java` with the `deleteById()`.

My Repository

```
import com.ipiecoles.java.eval2x0.model.Employe;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.awt.print.Pageable;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface EmployeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employe, Long> {
    /**
     * Méthode qui cherche un employé selon son matricule
     * @param matricule
     * @return l'employé de matricule correspondant, null sinon
     */
    Employe findByMatricule(String matricule);
}
```

My runner

```
private void afficheMenuSupprimerEmploye() {
        System.out.println("=====================================");
        System.out.println("Suppression de l'employé de matricule : ");
        String MatSupprimer = litString(REGEX_MATRICULE); // regex conditions
        System.out.println(MatSupprimer);

        Employe deleteEmploye =  employeRepository.findByMatricule(MatSupprimer);
        System.out.println(deleteEmploye); // return null ...

        Employe.deleteByID(MatSupprimer);

    }
```

Comment: Just a hint: By convention, variable names should start with a lowercase letter.(`MatSupprimer`)

Answer (score 1):

`deleteById` is not a static method of the entity (in your case `Employe`) itself, but a method of the repository.

Try `employeRepository.deleteById(theId)`; or if you already have the entity anyway, just `employeRepository.delete(Matsupprimer)`;

Also as said in the comment, I recommend making your variable Matsupprimer start with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

@Sebastiann is correct you need to use `employeRepository.deleteById(theId), but for that you should have id, while you have mentioned

> System.out.println(deleteEmploye); // return null ...

what does value contains of **MatSupprimer** in `Employe deleteEmploye =  employeRepository.findByMatricule(MatSupprimer);`

**employeRepository.deleteByID(MatSupprimer)** must looking for a **long** type id or delete entity object itself

Answer (score 0):

In your case `Employe` is hibernate entity. So you couldn't find  `deleteByID()` method in your `Employe` entity class